# New-ADUser other attributes The server is unwilling to process the request

Tags: powershell

When attempting to create New-ADUser cmd-let then I got the following the error message.

As summary ,  Each of these 2 variables may be $null or not $null

> if IpPhone is not null and  EmployeeType is null then I am getting
> error message or
>
> if IpPhone is  null and  EmployeeType is not null then I am getting
> error message or

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "pa$$word1" -AsPlainText -Force
New-ADuser -Name 'johnd' -GivenName 'John' -Surname 'Doe' -DisplayName 'John Doe' -AccountPassword $secpasswd -OtherAttributes @{'IpPhone'=1432434324; 'EmployeeType'=""}




The server is unwilling to process the request
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=John...ta,DC=com:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
    + PSComputerName        : xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: Does the call succeed if you remove `-OtherAttributes @{...}` completely? I suspect the issue is you never provide a samaccountname value

Comment: yes its works without -otherattributes

Comment: It's entirely possible it rejects the request because it won't accept `$null` values - have you tried just removing the corresponding key if that's the case? ie. if the `ipPhone` value is `$null`, just pass `-OtherAttributes @{EmployeeType='employee type goes here'}`

Comment: yes its works with `OtherAttributes @{EmployeeType='employee type goes here'}` without `IPPhone`

Comment: my question is : I want to run this script even though IPPhone and/or Employeetype attribute is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, the Domain Controller won't accept `$null` values for the fields specified in the `-OtherAttributes` hashtable.

So the solution is to only populate it with fields that have a value:

```
$otherAttrs = @{}
if($ipPhone){
  $otherAttrs['ipPhone'] = $ipPhone
}
if($employeeType){
  $otherAttrs['employeeType'] = $employeeType
}

New-ADUser ... -OtherAttributes $otherAttrs
```